# How can I detect a partial rectangle and align image using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was wondering how it would be possible to detect the bottom right corner of a paper square I manually made (which is probably not perfectly a square, because I drew it myself) on top of another object. What I want to do is use this square as a reference and align the image according to the bottom right corner of the square. I'm quite a Matlab amateur. Can anybody help?

The top left square is the paper square I need to detect which is the reference point.

[image: Example image with square at top left]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of choices to detect the square; it's actually a rectangle; you want to detect, but the easiest way is using morphological operations. Here I provided a commented script to help you; since you are a MATLAB amateur.

`ShowMaskAsOverlay` is not a built-in command in MATLAB, though, It is very useful. If you want to download it visit this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22108-showmaskasoverlay).

Another way I would suggest from what I understood from your question. You can save the image before making the square, and save another image after making the square. Then you will only need to get the difference between the two images.

```
close all;clear all;clc;

% Read in Image
im = imread('stack.png');

[r, c, ch] = size(im);

% Convert Image to Gray if it's RGB
if ch == 3
    gray = rgb2gray(im);
end

% Threshold Value; > 0.87 = 1 and  < 0.87 = 0
thresh = 0.87;
bw = im2bw(gray, thresh);

% Removing unwanted white pixels
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 400);
bw = imerode(bw, strel('disk', 3));
bw = imfill(bw, 'holes');
bw = bwareaopen(bw, 600);
bw = imdilate(bw, strel('disk', 3)); %optional. Could be omitted

% Calculating the BoundingBox of the Square
s = regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox');
box = struct2cell(s);
pos = cell2mat(box);

%% Displaying Images
figure(1)
imshow(im)
rectangle('position', pos, 'edgecolor', 'red', 'linewidth', 1.5)
str = ['Bounding Box Bottom Right Corner Coordinate Value = ', num2str(pos(4))];
h = text(pos(3), pos(4), num2str(pos(4)));
set(h, 'Color', 'k', 'FontSize', 12, 'FontWeight', 'bold')
title(str)

figure(2)
imshow(gray)
showMaskAsOverlay(0.5, bw, 'g')
```

[image]

Comment: hi Osama, thank you for your help! I have some more questions, if you don't mind!

Comment: I tried to look up the documentation, but it isn't clear to me what 'image erosion' really does in this case. Does it just try to make everything more disk shaped?

How does regionprops know what areas to measure?

Shouldn't the bottom right coordinates be two values, such as pos(3) and pos(4), or is there a reason why you only took pos(4)? Would it be possible to crop the image based on these coordinates, for example a 100x100 square 100 px to the right and 100px down starting from the bottom right of the white rectangle? Or do I need to convert the coordinates first?

Comment: @NGCake Erosion is a morphological operation where it removes scattered white pixels "1's". How does erosion make this? First you specify a structuring element 'strel'. I used 'disk' to avoid sharp edges if using rectangle or square.  Then the 'strel'; aka kernel or mask; scans the image in a zigzag way. If a white pixel surrounded by N number of black pixels. Then the white pixel is removed.

Comment: @NGCake regionpros is a very useful command in MATLAB. It only takes a logical image as its input. I used  'BoundingBox' property to get the box surrounding the white object detected; here the white top left corner. Then I got the coordinate of this box where [x,y,w,h] is [pos(1) pos(2) pos(3) pos(4)]. To crop a specific area in the image is possible. You have many ways to do so. Please be more specific what you want to crop so I can help you. At last consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Osama, thank you for your help! I accepted it! I think I got the cropping down now. Do you know how I could rotate the image based on the angle between the bottom right red corner and the top right of the white rectangle? So I guess I would need to find the coordinate of the top right white rectangle and then calculate the angle between a line between that point and the bottom right corner of the rectangle and a vertical line from the bottom right corner of the red rectangle?

Comment: I want to do this so I can get a sense of alignment when I take different pictures that may have a slight rotation.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you think it would be possible for the bounding box to get the actual bottom right white corner of the paper more accurately? Do I need a different type of box for this? Would it be better to use something like Hough transform? I think I understand how to find the top right now (based on the bw matrix).

Comment: Dear @NGCake, If you want to improve detection in this code, you can modify preprocessing. Using Hough Transform would be useless as you are trying to detect only a single rectangle, not all the line in the image. If you want to crop the image use the command `imcrop` and `imrotate` to rotate the image.

Comment: hello Osama, sorry to bother you again, but would you know how to adjust it to work on a 1280x1024 image? Since it has around 4x more pixels, I tried to make bwareopen 4x as big, but it doesn't seem to work? This would be an example picture http://imgur.com/a/IpzMf

Comment: What kind of preprocessing would you suggest to get the bottom right corner more accurately?